# Stacking Range of Columns Values by Index and Other Column Value

Tags: r

Okay, this seems like it is probably somewhat straightforward, but I am an R noob and can't seem to figure it out.

I read in a table from a csv file with two columns, where the first column is a  location name followed by the value of an observation taken at that location.  Only two locations exist, but there are many samples taken at each location which are in the second column.  I want to transform the table so that the locations become the column header, and the desired number of samples are stacked under the proper location by index range.

The script below shows what I want to do.

Thanks, in advance, for helping.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("A","B"), each = 5), col2 = 1:10)
df2 <- acast(df, col2 ~ col1, value.var = "col2")
```

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocqG8.png)

Current output has a bunch of NA values in it. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWbcS.png)

Desired output is:

```
# A B
  1 6
  2 7
  3 8
  4 9
  5 10
```

Comment: Unrelated, but there doesn't appear to be an option to edit my question when I view it.  Is that normal? Nevermind, found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("A","B", "C"), each = 5), col2 = 1:15)
do.call(cbind, split(df$col2, df$col1 ))
```

### input

```
#    col1 col2
# 1     A    1
# 2     A    2
# 3     A    3
# 4     A    4
# 5     A    5
# 6     B    6
# 7     B    7
# 8     B    8
# 9     B    9
# 10    B   10
# 11    C   11
# 12    C   12
# 13    C   13
# 14    C   14
# 15    C   15
```

### output

```
#      A  B  C
# [1,] 1  6 11
# [2,] 2  7 12
# [3,] 3  8 13
# [4,] 4  9 14
# [5,] 5 10 15
```

if you need the first N observation, say 3, you can do this:

```
 do.call(cbind, split(df$col2, df$col1 ))[1:3, ]
```

Comment: Cool, acast was what I was looking for to reshape!  In line 2 it appears you are populating the data, no?  Assuming the data was read in, do you know how I can take the first N observations from col2 for name in col1 before the reshape?  I can of course drop the rows after reshaping, but it isn't quite as elegant.

Comment: Yes, I populated a sample data for demonstration. It can be applied on read data such as `data.frame`. For the other part of your  question I need a clarification. Do you want to make the code one line? then you can `acast ...value.var = "col2")[1:3, ]` if you want the first 3 observation. I don't see why it isn't elegant to drop afterwards.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but something weird seems to be going on here.  The values in columns A and B should be treated as independent, but when I run your solution they all get jumbled together an null values pop up everywhere.  When I run a simple example with unique values for A and B, I also don't get what I would expect.

Comment: For example, check this output: df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("A","B"), each = 5), col2 = 1:10)  
df2 <- acast(df, col2 ~ col1, value.var = "col2")[1:3, ]

Comment: It  seems my solution was incorrect. I updated the solution and no need to use the 'reshape' library. I have tested with more columns and for different values.

Comment: Ahh, this is great.  Thank you!